# Wordpress error on post.php when trying to edit

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, http-status-code-500

We are receiving a 500 error on the post.php when trying to edit a custom post type.
This error is preventing the rest of the page and associated javascript components from loading, therefore this error is preventing the page from loading correcting and my users cannot edit lessons on our site.

I have tried replacing the htaccess, I have tried disabling plugins. Would this be the result of not allocating enough php memory? This is a high volume, high traffic site with considerable amount of customisation.

[image]

I have spoken with our host and there are no specific php errors. I have also run a debug and can only see small deprecation errors that shouldnt be causing this issue.

I have also created a mirror version of the site on a staging server and this seems to work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, a 500 error could be caused by just about anything. Out-of-memory, function causing a fatal error, etc. There very much should be an error log somewhere. If not you may need to enable `WP_DEBUG` to see what's causing it.

Comment: Try enabling debug mode via wp-config.php. BTW error 500 happens on the server, either wrong code or missing extensions on server. 500 errors are logged into the web server error logs.

Comment: seems that revslider might be consuming too much memory PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /usr/www/users/site/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/slide.class.php

Answer (score 0):

By enabling the debugger we determined that the issue was a php memory issue. A redundant plugin was consuming too much memory, thereby hindering someof the features from being run on the site.